# Parsing a non-standard date string in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon, xpath-2.0

I am attempting to parse a date string in XSLT2.0/XPath2.0. The problem is, the date is not in a standard format, and will therefore require calculations, not just string manipulation. To be specific, the dates come in the pattern "yyyyDDD" (Yes, that's right, the year followed by the day of the year).

For an example, 2013051 == Feb. 20, 2013

I have been researching this question for a while now, and have found many answers that don't help me, such as:

- Parsing the date with substring: I need to calculate the month & day from the day of the year
- date:parse-date: Not supported by Saxon (I am currently using an evaluation version of SaxonEE, if support for this extension function can be added I am willing to listen!)
- Use scripting: I am trying to move away from MSXML/Javascript in the XSLTs in an attempt to simplify the code, and would like to avoid going back there if I can avoid
- Calculate the date by hand: These days, you need a PhD in dates just to get them right... there are too many edge cases for me to feel safe reinventing the wheel here
- Pass in dates to the XSLT in a standard format: To fall back on the classic programmers' dilemma, I have no control over the inputs to this XSLT.

The Java method Date.parse() is *exactly* what I need here, and I am finding it hard to believe that there is no standard way of handling dates in XSLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath 2 does not have special *parsing* functions, but it has many functions for date time *calculations*.

So you can create a date for the first day in the year and then add the day offset to it. If the input string is in `$input`, just insert this xpath expression in your XSLT:

```
xs:date(concat(substring($input, 1, 4), "-01-01")) + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat("P",number(substring($input,5, 3)) - 1, "D"))
```

Comment: I love everything about this solution, especially the fact that it works perfectly! Just goes to show you that sometimes you need to look at a problem from a different angle :)